# How to test if names are nicknames of each other?

Tags: sql, duckdb

I'm an experienced SWE, just new to SQL and would love a walkthrough on how to solve this particular problem.

I have an input table of name pairs. I need to determine if each pair of names are nicknames of each other or not:

| left | right | desired |
| --- | --- | --- |
| john | johnathon | True |
| jon | john | True |
| john | amy | False |
| etc... | etc.. | etc... |

To do this, I have at my disposal [a lookup table](https://github.com/carltonnorthern/nicknames/blob/6f86f30dd143e023321e3da5ba58f1cbc850fce0/sql/names_normalized.sql) that links together canonical names and nicknames:

| canonical_name | nickname |
| --- | --- |
| johnathon | jon |
| johnathon | john |
| john | jon |
| etc... | etc.. |

What SQL query would get me there? Something with JOINs and IN statements I'm guessing, but I haven't gotten anything to work. I'm using DuckDB, but I'm guessing the solution is going to be general enough that the dialect of SQL shouldn't matter? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the names 'input' and 'lookup' to your tables, this should work:

```
SELECT 
i.left, 
i.right,
--See join comments
(l1.nickname IS NOT NULL OR l2.canonical_name IS NOT NULL) AS Desired

FROM
input AS i
--Assume left input is a canonical name. 
--Left join to lookups to get a column with nicknames if match is found, else null
LEFT JOIN lookup AS l1 ON i.left=l1.canonical_name
--As above but the other way around
LEFT JOIN lookup AS l2 ON i.left=l2.nickname
```

This answer is formatted for SSMS but the idea should be similar elsewhere.

Edit: Another answer that discards duplicates.

```
SELECT *
FROM input
WHERE
(left  IN (select nickname from lookup where canonical_name=right)) OR
(right IN (select nickname from lookup where canonical_name=left))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @dc-ddfe! This doesn't work because the result will have many more rows than the input. This is because the lookup table has many duplicate entries for a single canonical_name or nickname (see in my example how jon and jonathon appear multiple times)

Comment: Fair point. Is the edited version closer to what you need?